# ASP MVC 5 TempData not working with RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redirect, tempdata

I have the following tempdata in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string query = null)
    {

        TempData["message"] = string.Format("test message");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
    }
```

And in my _layout.cshtml file I have the following:

```
 @if (TempData["message"] != null)
 {
      <div class="message">@TempData["message"]</div>
 }
```

But nothing get displayed. If do the following i.e. no redirect from my controller method, the message gets displayed.

```
public ActionResult Index(string query = null)
{

        TempData["message"] = string.Format("test message");

         return View();

}
```

So basically it doesnt seem to work on RedirectToAction. Strangely it was working before so not sure what has happend all of a sudden?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks absolutely fine. Are you reading the TempData anywhere else ?

Comment: @Shyju No, not reading the TempData anywhere else.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this. I am also having the same issue. Looks like it happens when I add httpcookie in web.config.                                     <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="true" />

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize the object before assigning it to TempData. For example,

```
AccountHolderDetails user = new AccoundHolderDetails();
TempData["UserData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

and retrieve the object by deserializing it.

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountHolderDetails>(TempData["UserData"].ToString());
```